# Microservice: Service discovery and Service Registry with Akka

Tags: akka, microservices

I'm going to apply Microservices architecture for my application. The internal communication between microservices will be achieved by using Akka. But I don't know how to make all microservices aware and register each other. I have some options to design Service Registry and Discovery:

1) Use Zookeeper as a centrailized service to hold all metadata of all microservices (nodes) and let them access these metadata to communicate. The metadata of each node contains Akka path (address) information to let the other nodes communicate to.

2) Join all microservices (Akka Nodes) to an Akka Cluster and each node will keep reference of each other to communicate. Akka Cluster supports gossip protocol and it will let all nodes in cluster aware together.

Can anybody give me some advices about this? How to design Service Discovery and Service Registry efficiently on top of Akka? Are there any options for this?

Comment: You wrote "the internal communication between microservices will be achieved by using akka".  Does this mean each service will use akka http or will they communicate with each other directly through akka?

Comment: I mean they will communicate with each other directly (via TCP using Kryo serialization). After services are discovered from registry then each service will communicate directly via Akka

Comment: any updates on this? did you find a best practice that worked for you?
Thanks

Comment: Not yet, we want to use Akka but it doesn't work as expected so we move to Spring boot application. If you can suggest any ideas then it's will be great.

Answer (score 1):

I've been building similar distributed applications since a while using the second approach you suggested, in which microservices run in an Akka Cluster, with few predefined seeder nodes. Each microservice identifies itself using Roles, and has a list of roles that it's interested in.

Each node/microservice has an actor listening to Member Events which is responsible for keeping path address' for nodes interested in, and also it acts as a router for inter-node messages.

I'm fine with this approach, it provides scalability in and out easily.

Comment: How about CI/CD and deployment for this Akka CLuster. How to deploy Akka CLuster to Kubernetes?